# How to show a currently unknown number of libraries in a Deployment Diagram

Tags: deployment, uml

My system is still at the concept stage, but I'm creating a Deployment Diagram to focus discussions about the end result. The system will have some run-time subroutine libraries. At at this stage there is no way to know how many there will be: in fact the number may never stabilize, since it will depend on various other aspects of the system.

A library is an artifact with stereotype "library" in guillemets. Several ways to diagram the unknown number come to mind:

1. Show one library, with a note attached saying that the number of libraries is unknown
2. Put an asterisk at the upper right of the library artifact, as with composite structure diagrams
3. Draw a slanted stack of overlapping artifacts
4. Don't diagram them individually: just list "library 1, library 2, library 3..."
5. Use a "manifest" relationship a between an artifact and an asterisked-component.

And there must be lots of other creative possibilities.

Does anyone know if there's a UML-prescribed way to show this unknown number of libraries on a Deployment Diagram, and if so, what it is?

Comment: model what you know at deployment level, to try to model/show unknown artifacts has no sense nor interest.

Comment: Though still at the concept stage, we already know some things about the deployment structure. For example, we know there will be subroutine libraries to manage...we just don't know what they all are yet. I, and the people I'm working with, are interested in this fact and want to present it visually. If you don't share this interest, we can both be pleased that we work on separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your *logical* Deployment Model (abstract) that shows *classes* of Artefacts, Components, Nodes etc. from your physical Deployment Model(s) (concrete) that show specific *instances* of those Artefacts, Components and Nodes etc. At the logical level, you could show an abstract Artefact called "Library" that has associations with plural multiplicities to Nodes, Components etc. in your logical design. Then, you could specialise that abstract Artefact, and at the concrete Deployment Model(s) level, create *instances* of these Library specialisations that are associated with instances of Nodes, Components etc.

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea: I'll try that out.  Thank you.